# PHP: a way to check user login other than sessions

Tags: php, session

I am building a website and I am using sessions to check user login. I am wondering if there is any better and safer way to check user login. Because sessions are stored in the clients computer I think they are not very safe and easy to hack. Am I correct?How do big websites like facebook and twitter check if their user is logged in or not. I am new to PHP so dont say my question is too basic.

Comment: The only way someone is going to hack a session, is if they're in your actual computer. You can also use a token in conjunction with sessions.

Comment: Sessions, sessions and sessions... you may use different ways to persist sessions, but in the end its all about sessions!! :D

Comment: *"I am new to PHP..."* --- Remember, when using sessions, you will need to have `session_start();` inside every page used. This should be your first line after your opening PHP tag, most of the time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks.I have session_start(); in my header page and include it in every page.

Comment: @user1763032 You're welcome. You're good to go then ;-)

Comment: @user1763032 Here is what I use (modified for my own use of course). Although for a different application, it works marvels (uses sessions and tokens). http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are definitely the way to go here.

No matter what you use as authentication, if the client computer is compromised, the client's method of authentication can be abused. So in this regard, any other way can only be as safe as sessions are.

All big sites use sessions, usually in conjunction with cookies.

Answer (score 4):

Sessions are not stored in the client's computer. You must be confused with cookies !

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought sessions were stored in the clients computer. So, if the sessions are stored in the server there is no way to hack them?

Comment: Cookies can contain entire sessions. Hence when someone says they store their entire sessions on the client side it can possibly be true. (Although the method would be far too unsafe to be practically of any use for authentication.)

Comment: @user1763032, Am not saying sessions are 100% secure. `Session Hijacking` is a seperate topic. But's that not an easy job.

Answer (score 1):

I want you to first understand that Sessions are the only way you can identify a client.

You don't store sessions on either the client or server side. (If you want a secure system.)

First you need to understand the need for sessions, only then you can know what sessions are.

The internet is a stateless network of machines, each with their own identifiers. Most of the communication that we do while sending a request to load a page or visit various links are over the HTTP (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol).

HTTP is a stateless protocol, meaning any communication over this protocol is not required by the protocol to be stored on either the server or client.

Let us understand what this would mean, with an example:

Suppose you try to login to http://example.com

1. You fill the form, hit the send button.
2. All the data in your form is then sent to the server.
3. The server checks if the username and password received was right. If right, it sends you the secure data.
4. In your next call to the web server, you expect to be logged in. BUT, due to the stateless nature of HTTP, your server does not recognize you anymore.

You can make this work by sending your username and password with every call, but that would mean having to enter it every-time for each request.

Here comes the role of cookies, you set the username cookie as `Joe` and password cookie as `qwerty`. Now everytime a request is sent the cookies are sent by the browser and you are happy.

This scenario now again has a problem that you need to make an authentication check everytime on your server thus increasing the load on it.

Enter Sessions. Sessions mean states with some context. It may be a logged in user, it may contain preferences you have set or any other similar stuff.

Here, when the user is logged in the first time, the server generates a session ID. This session ID is then stored by the server in a DB, File or it's Memory (RAM) along with any other data like username of the person who is logged in, preferences etc.

The server response then contains the session ID, which may be in the form of a cookie, HTML5 session states or sometimes even hidden fields.

Now, every call the client makes, contains the session ID. The server then checks its session store for any valid sessions with the same ID and get into context therby giving a pseudo state-like mechanism to communications taking place over HTTP.

How long your browser stores this cookie can also be determined by the server while sending the cookie.

There are advanced techniques for further security like changing the session ID each time a call is made, but lets get into that only if you want me to.

Cheers! :)